# Run array to get texture_type in React.js

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, rest

I'm still confused with .map in ReactJs, everytime I try to use it, I get **.map undefined**. I need to go through an array that results of a fetch from an API that looks like the following image:

```
Array(20)
    0:
        couch_model: 1
        couchmodelextralayout_set: (4) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]
        created_on: "date"
        dimensions_3D: "309cm D: 28.5cm H: 84cm"
        dimensions_price: Array(3)
            0:
                arm: 28.5
                dimensions: "331.5"
                price_table_code: "table_1"
                prices: Array(5)
                    0:
                        final_price: 0
                        texture_type: "Diamante"
                    1: {…},
                    2: {…},
                    3: {…},
                    4: {…}
```

Basically this:

[image]

This is my actual code:

```
export class Material extends React.Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            isLoaded: false,
            textures: {}
        };
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        const email = email;
        const pass = pass;
        const url = url;

        /* Here is fetch to get token */

        fetch(url + '/layout/?limit=20', {
            method: 'GET',
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                'Accept': 'application/json',
                'Authorization': 'JWT ' + (JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('token')).token)
            }
        }).then(res => {
            if (res.ok) {
                return res.json();
            } else {
                throw Error(res.statusText);
            }
        }).then(json => {
            this.setState({
                textures: json
            }, () => {
                console.log('textures: ', json);
            });
        })

    }



    render() {

        const { isLoaded, textures } = this.state;


        if (!isLoaded) {

            return (
                <div>{/*nothing*/}</div>
            )

        } else {

            return (
                <div>
                {/*
                    This is where I want the texture to appear
                */}
                </div>
            );

        }
    }
}
```

Basically, I want to show all the textures in different `<p>` tags, but i don't know how to access the array... Any suggestions?

Comment: Provide that array in the question and not the image.

Comment: The array comes from the fetch @AnkitAgarwal

Comment: You can console log and paste that array here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the result of your fetch (`textures`) is actually an array, the .map function should work properly.
The problem can come from the declaration of state.textures in your constructor: you initialise it as an object.
By doing this the first render of your component try to .map on an empty object.

Try to initialise it as an array like this

```
this.state = {
    isLoaded: false,
    textures: []
};
```

**EDIT :**

In the last part of your fetch, you need to refer to json.results intead of simply json which is the object containing the results array

```
.then(json => {
    this.setState({
        textures: json.results
    }, () => {
        console.log('textures: ', json);
    });
 })
```

### If you want to keep the whole object in your state,

you can initialise the state the same way you did :

```
this.state = {
    isLoaded: false,
    textures: {}
};
```

Keep the last part of your fetch unchanged :

```
this.setState({
  textures: json
}
```

And map the results like this in the render :

```
const { isLoaded, textures } = this.state;

return(
      {
        textures.results.map(result=>(
           ...
        ))
      }
)
```

Comment: Changed that and still `textures.map is not a function`

Comment: So the result of your fetch is probably not an array. Do you have a log of it?

Comment: Sorry, I wrote the array because Ankit asked and I had the image and I deleted by mistake. Check the question again please :) @Jayffe

Comment: `this.setState({textures: json.results}` instead of `this.setState({ textures: json }` should be a good start to have the results array from your fetch

Comment: Yes, that helped, but now, I wrote this `return (
                <div>
                    {textures.map(texture =>
                        <p key={texture.id}>{texture.dimensions_price.prices.texture_type}</p>
                    )}
                </div>
            );` and says `TypeError: Cannot read property 'texture_type' of undefined`

Comment: `prices` and `dimensions_price` are arrays, so `{texture.dimensions_price[0].prices[0].texture_type}` should give you the first texture_type of the first dimension_price

Comment: `Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): Cannot read property 'prices' of undefined`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/177017/discussion-between-jayffe-and-sofia-ribeiro).

Comment: Can you go to the discussion? @Jayffe